# StaticContentNotFoundException when accessing published image media

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

I added images to an Article Component and added it to a Page and published it. I can see the image in the Broker DB and the view prints out the url correctly
`/en/media/bg-brands-by-services_tcm9-11090.png`. But I get the below exception:

> ERROR c.s.w.m.c.core.MainController - Exception while processing
>   request for: /en/media/bg-brands-by-services_tcm9-11090.png
>   com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.StaticContentNotFoundException: No
>   binary variant found for: [9]
>   /en/media/bg-brands-by-services_tcm9-11090.png    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.DD4TStaticContentProvider.getStaticContentFile(DD4TStaticContentProvider.java:118)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.dd4t.DD4TStaticContentProvider.getStaticContent(DD4TStaticContentProvider.java:82)
>   ~[dd4t-provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sdl.webapp.main.interceptor.StaticContentInterceptor.preHandle(StaticContentInterceptor.java:65)
>   ~[core-module-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:130)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.R

Comment: Did you double check the deployer is using the same database as the web application is? Also is this issue only showing up with this new image, or is the rest of the website also not showing any images?

Comment: Its only happenening for this image. Other images appear properly

Comment: Check the cd_storage.config on your webapp.  Do you have settings in there for .png file extensions?